# Linux mint 17.3 without HDMI sound output

Tags: drivers, audio, alsa, pulseaudio, hdmi

Well, tried everything: alsa, alsa-utils, alsamixer, pulseaudio, puvecontrol and a lot more. Even I changed from ubuntu to Linux mint, but I can't get sound from hdmi (laptop connected to led tv). I have a desktop pc with linux mint connected to a led tv with the same hdmi cable and works. I'm trying to make it work for a laptop Asus X555LA-XX688H. The HDMI option does not show up in sound settings neither in pavucontrol settings.

> aplay -L

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC233 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

> uname -r

```
3.13.0-24-generic
```

I tried with **oem-audio-hda-daily** too. But I have and other problem: I can't see additional drivers option in linux mint 17.3. Only Software origins.

> lshw -C display

```
*-display               
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 2
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       versión: 09
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuración: driver=i915 latency=0
       recursos: irq:64 memoria:b1000000-b1ffffff memoria:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed updating the kernel version. **3.18.29** worked for me.

> aplay -L | grep hdmi

```
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=1
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=2
```